# Combine rows and fill NaN values within groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following `DataFrame`:

```
    X   Y   Z   
0   xxx NaN 333 
1   NaN yyy 444     
2   xxx NaN 333     
3   NaN yyy 444
```

I am trying to combine `rows` based on the `Z` `column` to get the following:

```
    X   Y   Z   
0   xxx yyy 333 
1   xxx yyy 444
```

Comment: I think your example is off. Both rows with `Z = 333` have `NaN` in the `Y` column. Should the `Z` column be `[333, 333, 444, 444]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should

1. group by the label column, and
2. within each group, backfill `NaN` values, and return the first row.

For example,

```
def flatten(g):
    return g.fillna(method='bfill').iloc[0]

df.groupby('Z').apply(flatten).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

For this particular example, you can do:

```
df.fillna(method='ffill').fillna(method='bfill').drop_duplicates()

     X    Y    Z
0  xxx  yyy  333
1  xxx  yyy  444
```

Not sure if you are looking for something more general?